# Add parent child whenever onchild created cloud function real time database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Here I have code that trigger ref `/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}` whenever child added will send notification to the android device. It already doing really well. But I want to add one more function inside it, I want to add child outside this ref called `flag_tugas` and will be populate with `flag_tugas-course_id-tugas_id-user.uid: "o"`. I dont know how to add it, because the return value already take it all and how to get users id in cloud function.

```
export const onNotifTugas = functions.database.ref('/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{


    const course_id = context.params.course_id;
    const tugas_id = context.params.tugas_id;

    console.log(`New Message ${course_id} in ${tugas_id}`);

    return admin.database().ref('/tugas/' + tugas_id +'/').once('value').then(snap => {
            const tugasData = snap.val();
            const notifDataSend = { // buat structure data json dgn nama const notifDataSend untul cloud messaging
                data: {
                            data_type: "tugas",
                            title: "Anda mendapatkan notifikasi baru..", // data bebas (key, value)
                            body: `Tugas ${tugasData.nama_tugas} baru`, // chatId = const chatId
                            sound: "default"
                      }
             };

            console.log(`data yang dikirim `);
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(course_id, notifDataSend) 

            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
              })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
              });

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })

});


    }
```

Actually adding the new child under eclassapp 
[image]

Really thanks for your time and answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure to fully understand where you want to add the timestamp in your node tree (under `/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}/new_child` or under `/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}`) but the following code will work for adding a `timestamp` value right under `/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}`. If you need you can change the value of ref to write the timestamp where you want.

```
exports.onNotifTugas = functions.database
  .ref('/tugas_course/{course_id}/{tugas_id}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const ref = snapshot.ref;
    const ts = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    return ref.update({
      date_time: ts
    });
  });
```

---

Note however that you don't need a Cloud Function to add a timestamp from the server, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue

So in your case you would do something like:

```
var tugaRef = firebase.database().ref("/tugas_course/course_id/tugas_id");
tugaRef.push({
  foo: bar,  //Other data of your 'tugas' object
  createdAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
})
```

Comment: I just want to when I create child in that ref, so it will add one more child which is time that post being created. For specific information, I want to child called "date_time" and contains value like "Tue Apr 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2013"

Comment: Just adapt the `ref` value in the answer to fulfill your needs. I've renamed `createdAt` field to `date_time`. The timestamp value correspond to the format you are looking for.

Comment: Sir, now I realize I have to add child like this. I have been updated my code